# form pass selected to next page

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, mysqli

I have a selector which gets data from my Database.

[image: The selector]

When I select 1 item and press `Add to list`, it generates a table:

[image: When I selected something]

the code for this all is:

```
    <!--Selector-->
    <?php

// Get name and id data from the db. In an assoc array

$results = $database->Selector();
echo "<form name='form' method='POST' id='selector'>";
echo "<select name='train_name' id='train_name' multiple='multiple'>";

// Loop trough the results and make an option of every train_name

foreach($results as $res) {
    echo "<option value=" . $res['train_name'] . ">" . $res['train_name'] . "</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
echo "<br />" . "<td>" . "<input type='submit' name='Add' value='Add to list'/>" . "</td>";
echo "</form>";

if (isset($_POST["train_name"])) {

    // Get all data from database, in an assoc array

    $results = $database->getAllAssoc();

    // Make table headers

?>
            <div id="train_select_table">
            <form name="selector" method="post" action="customer_list.php?user_id=<?php
    echo $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Train name</th>
                        <th>Number of bogies</th>
                        <th>Number of axles</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                        <th>More info</th>
                        <th>Check</th>
                    <!--Only for admins (later!)-->
                    <!--<th>XML</th>
                        <th>SQL</th>    -->
                    </tr>
                <div id="looprow">
                    <?php
    foreach($results as $res) {

        // Loop trough results, generate a tablerow every time

?>
                    <tr>     
                        <td name="train_name"><?php
        echo $res['train_name'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php
        echo $res['number_of_bogies'] ?></td>
                        <td><?php
        echo $res['number_of_axles'] ?></td>
                        <td><a href="remove_from_table.php?train_id=<?php
        echo $res['train_id'] ?>">Delete</a></td>
                        <td><a href="expand_info.php?train_id=<?php
        echo $res['train_id'] ?>">More Information</a></td> 
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<?php
        echo $res['train_id'] ?>"></td>
                                                    <!--Only for admins (later!)--> 
                        <!--<td><a href="convert_to_xml.php?train_id=<?php
        echo $res['train_id'] ?>">XML</a></td>
                        <td><a href="convert_to_sql.php?train_id=<?php
        echo $res['train_id'] ?>">SQL</a></td>-->
                    </tr>
                <?php
    }

?>
                </div>
            </table><br />
            <input name="Add to list" type="submit" id="add_to_list" value="add_to_list">
        </form>
        </div>
        <?php
}

?>

Functions:

    function getAllAssoc() {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE train_name = :train_name";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(":train_name", $_POST["train_name"]);
            $sth->execute();
            return $sth->fetchAll();
        }
    
    function selector() {
            $sql = "SELECT train_name, train_id FROM train_information";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);   
            $sth->execute();
            return $sth->fetchAll();
        }
```

When I Check the check button, and press `Add to list` . You will go to `customer_list.php` . On this page I want to show the information of the selected item. What I have right now is:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST["checkbox"];
?>
```

This shows me a number (when I selected a item) which is the ID of the train/item.

But how do I show all the information of the selected checkbox?
Also if I have multiple trains in the table, for example 10. And I only select 7 and press the button. I want the next page `customer_list.php` to show those specific 7 results.

Comment: Use your logic. Process the value you get in the customer_list.php.

Comment: But how? Becuase i get to correct value of the selection. wich is a ID. but when i do like: <td name="train_name"> and Post that on the next page just like the selection. it won't post anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit checkbox code as :

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="<?php echo $res['train_id']?>"></td>
```

customer_list.php code:

```
<?php

function getAllAssoc_id($id) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE id = :id";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":id", $id);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }

    //echo $_POST["checkbox"];

    echo"<table><tr><td>Train Name</td><td>Train Id</td></tr>";
    foreach($_POST["checkbox"] as $key=>$val){
    $data=getAllAssoc_id($val);
    echo"<tr><td>".$data['train_name']."</td><td>".$data['id']."</td></tr>";

    }
    echo"</table";
?>
```

Comment: i get this error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context and Notice: Array to string conversion. But i may figure it out

Comment: You need to include databses connection files as in your form/other pages

Comment: You need to remove echo $_POST["checkbox"] for your notice.

Comment: Removed it, only got the fatal error: Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context. The connections etc. are required aswell (already were)

Comment: write the whole function function getAllAssoc_id in the class in which other functions function getAllAssoc()  exists

Comment: when i do that, and edit the function call to: $data = $database->getAllAssoc_id($val); i get 2 notices: Notice: Undefined index: train_name and Notice: Undefined index: id

Comment: I have try to explain you the basic things rest of the things you need to look yourself

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1.Change

```
echo "<select name='train_name' id='train_name' multiple='multiple'>";
```

to

```
echo "<select name='train_name[]' id='train_name' multiple='multiple'>";
```

2.Change

```
function getAllAssoc() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE train_name = :train_name";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":train_name", $_POST["train_name"]);
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

to

```
function getAllAssoc() {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM train_information WHERE train_name IN(:train_name)";
        $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(":train_name", implode(",",$_POST["train_name"]));
        $sth->execute();
        return $sth->fetchAll();
    }
```

Just adjust the quotes in the query as I have not tested this code and feel that there will be an issue with single quotes.

What is done above is that we have taken the inputs in an array and accordingly fetched the results based on this array input.

Hope you get the idea!!

Answer (score -1):

You have to take your checkbox name as an array ie `name="checkbox[]"`, so on the action page you will get an array of ids. Now you just have to query selected train_id's using mysql "IN" clause.

I can show you a query

```
Select * from table where train_id IN(array you got from check boxes)
```