# Array to string conversion on Insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo, mysqli

So i have a selector wich is based on my Database. Once people select something from that selector, select it and press next. They will see this page:

*(Selected train02 in example here)*

[image: Selected something from the DB]

Code for this is:

```
<form method="POST" action="add_to_summary.php?user_id=<?php echo $_SESSION['user_id']?>">
            <div id="customer_list_table">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Train id</th>
                        <th>Train Name</th>
                        <th>Tare Weight</th>
                        <th>Numbers of bogies</th>
                        <th>Numbers of axles</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                        foreach($_POST["checkbox"] as $key=>$val){
                        $data = $database->getAllAssoc_id($val);
                        foreach($data as $data1) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <input type='hidden' name='user_id[<?php echo $_GET['user_id']?>]' value='<?php echo $_GET['user_id']?>'>
                                <input type='hidden' name='train_id[<?php echo $data1['train_id']?>]' value='<?php echo $data1['train_id']?>'>
                                <td><?= $data1['train_id'] ?></td>
                                <td><?= $data1['train_name'] ?></td>
                                <td><?= $data1['tare_weight'] ?></td>
                                <td><?= $data1['number_of_bogies'] ?></td>
                                <td><?= $data1['number_of_axles'] ?></td>
                            </tr><?php
                        }
                    } ?>
                </table>
                </div>
            <input name="Add to list" type="submit" id="add_to_list" value="Add to list">
        </form>
```

When they press Add to list, an insert gets send to my database like this:

```
function summary_add($id) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO user_train_information "
        . "(train_id, user_id)"
        . "VALUES (:train_id, :user_id) ";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(':train_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->execute();
    }
```

Code on the `add_to_summary.php`:

```
<?php
        foreach($_POST['user_id'] as $id) {
            $test = $database->summary_add($id);
        }
?>
```

Now, info gets inserted in my DB. but double the one i selected. like this:

[image: what it does]

And when i change `$_POST['user_id']` to `$_POST['train_id']` it inputs **14** 2 times.

When i just do `foreach($_POST as $id)`, i get 2 array to string conversion errors.

How do i fix this???

I want the table to insert correctly so that the `user_id` column will be **1**, and the `train_id` column **14**
***EDIT:***
for the selector / selection boxes: [form pass selected to next page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30213135/form-pass-selected-to-next-page)

***EDIT:***
It is working right now!

What is changed:

Changed the to hidden fields:

```
<input type='hidden' name='user_id' value='<?php echo $_GET['user_id']?>'>
<input type='hidden' name='train_id' value='<?php echo $data1['train_id']?>'>
```

The function:

```
function summary_add($train_id, $user_id) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO user_train_information "
        . "(train_id, user_id)"
        . "VALUES (:train_id, :user_id) ";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(':train_id', $train_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->execute();
    }
```

Where i insert it:

```
<?php
            $test = $database->summary_add($_POST['train_id'], $_POST['user_id']);
            print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: so, where are your checkbox codes?

Comment: Those are not needed since they already work, but il edit them in anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function summary_add($train_id, $user_id) {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO user_train_information "
        . "(train_id, user_id)"
        . "VALUES (:train_id, :user_id) ";
            $sth = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
            $sth->bindParam(':train_id', $train_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $sth->execute();
    }
```

Code on the add_to_summary.php:

```
<?php
            $test = $database->summary_add($_POST['train_id'][0], $_POST['user_id'][0]);
?>
```

Summary: you have to put both the train_id and the user_id in your `summary_add` function.

Comment: What do you mean with: (/* Do your logic here */) ? I don't get it haha

Comment: I assume it was something like "Iterate over this the way you want to iterate", in other words your previous  "foreach" or "for" loop

Comment: When i use my previous loop: foreach($_POST['train_id'] as $id) {
            $test = $database->summary_add($_POST['train_id'], $_POST['user_id']);
        } i get array to string conversions. This is because i don't know what else to put in the loop haha

Comment: Also when i remove the loop and just do this: $test = $database->summary_add($_POST['train_id'], $_POST['user_id']); i get array to string conversion

Comment: Try to do print_r($_POST) and see what this array looks like.

Comment: Loop: <?php
   foreach($_POST['train_id'] as $id) { 
    $test = $database->summary_add($_POST['train_id'], $_POST['user_id']); 
   }
   print_r($_POST)
  ?>         I get 2 array to string conversions this way. with the print_r i get this: Array ( [user_id] => Array ( [1] => 1 ) [train_id] => Array ( [16] => 16 ) [Add_to_list] => Add to list )

Comment: Ok that's nice. As you see, the $_POST array exist of two new arrays: the user_id array and the train_id array. What you've got to do now is get 1 item from the user_id array and 1 item from the train_id array. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Now i get the error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 (2 times) and a fatal error: Train_id cannot be NULL (Because he wants to insert it but it cannot be NULL)